# Get the top part of the Window using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, navbar

I'm making a Navbar. Well, it is working correctly (I scroll down and the style changes), but then, when I scroll to the top, the styles stay the same. Is there a way to change styles when I scroll to the top part?

Here's the HTML

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <a href="#"><span>Visit San Francisco</span></a>
</div>
```

Here's the JavaScript:

```
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
var cover = document.querySelector(".cover");

function changeNavbarStyle() {
    navbar.classList.add("postConv");
}

function removeNavbarStyle() {
    navbar.classList.remove("postConv");
}

body.onscroll = changeNavbarStyle;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML DOM `onScroll` event.
So your HTML code would look like:

```
<body id="body" onscroll="scroll()">
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#"><span>Visit San Francisco</span></a>
    </div>
</body>
```

And in your JavaScript code you will define your `scroll()` method like:

```
function scroll() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementById("body");
    var y = elmnt.scrollTop;
    if(y == 0) {
        navbar.classList.remove("postConv");
    } else {
        navbar.classList.add("postConv");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried it out and it worked perfectly. Thanks man! :D

Answer (score 0):

Most of modern browsers such as "Firefox", "Opera", "Edge", ... use `document.documentElement.scrollTop` to detect the position of scroll from top of the page. So maybe if you change your script as follows, it works:

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
var cover = document.querySelector(".cover");

function changeNavbarStyle() {
    navbar.classList.add("postConv");
    if(document.documentElement.scrollTop === 0) {
        removeNavbarStyle();
    }
}

function removeNavbarStyle() {
    navbar.classList.remove("postConv");
}

body.onscroll = changeNavbarStyle;
```

```css
body {
    min-height: 850px;
}

.postConv {
    background-color: #c5bdd1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>nav-style</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
        <a href="#"><span>Visit San Francisco</span></a>
    </div>
      
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know nothing about this one, so; 1. I solved my problem, and, 2. I learnt something new. Thanks man! :D